# Can you understand protoc running with no errors, but not generating source files?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have downloaded protocol buffers (2.6.0) and I am trying to compile the `.proto` files.  I run the following from inside the downloaded `protobuf-2.6.0` directory

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc-2.6.0

$ cd java
$ protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

$ ls src/main/java
com
```

There are no errors on the protoc command, but the compilation should have generated source files in `src/main/java/google/protobuf`

- `--java_out` specifies where generated Java source files should go
- `-I` specifies the directory where imports can be found

I see nothing wrong with my command. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Ah! This question is not asking the right thing.  The source files are generated, but the package differs to what I expected.  The descriptor.proto file has 'package google.protobuf', but the sources are put in 'com.google.protubuf'.  Should I delete the question, or edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question premise is false.  The sources are being generated, but go under `src/main/java/com/google/protobuf` rather than `src/main/java/google/protobuf` as one might expect from the package name in `descriptor.proto`.

Edit - the java package name is given in the proto file like so:

```
package google.protobuf;
option java_package = "com.google.protobuf";
```

Comment: Correct. Java code is expected to be organized by Java package name. In contrast, C++ generated code will be organized according to the directory structure of the input `.proto` files.

Answer (score 1):

Your -I option seems incomplete. It should be

```
-I../src/google/protobuf/
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, adding the full path to the import statement did not change the result (I assumed it searched -I recursively).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The question's original `-I../src` is correct. `-I` should specify the "canonical source root". Since the file is always imported as `import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto;`, the `-I` flag should NOT include `google/protobuf`. (In this case, the difference is subtle. Specifying `-I../src/google/protobuf` will not cause an error, but the source code's embedded descriptor will be wrong.)